# Pagination keeps on adding when changing values

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, pagination

I have a website that lets the user choose on how many data they want to show on screen.

Whenever I try to select option2 from option1 my pagination just appends from the previous one. For example my previous pagination was 1,2,3 then when I clicked on option2 it became 1,2,3,1,2,3,4 when I only wanted it to be 1,2,3,4 only.

Index.html:

```html
<select class="form-select">
  <option selected disabled>Select an option</option>
  <option value="1">option1</option>
  <option value="2">option2</option>
  <option value="3">option3</option>
  <option value="4">option4</option>
</select>
```

Script.js:

```js
$('select').on('change', function(){
    var limit= $(this).val();
    displayPagination(limit)
});

function displayPagination(limit) {
    var limitPerPage = limit;
    
    //more codes here

    //pagination
    $(".pagination").append("<li class='current-page active'><a class='page-link' href='javascript:void(0)'>" + 1 + "</a></li>");

    for (var i = 2; i <= totalPages; i++) {
      $(".pagination").append("<li class='current-page'><a class='page-link' href='javascript:void(0)'>" + i + "</a></li>"); // Insert page number into pagination tabs
    }

    $(".pagination").append("<li class='page-item' id='next-page'><a class='page-link'   href='javascript:void(0)' aria-label=Next><span aria-hidden=true>&raquo;</span></a></li>");

    //more codes
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want to empty the contents of `$(".pagination")` before appending every value to it?

Comment: Ah yes, That's the right term for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are not clearing the previous pagination before adding new pages to it.
Try this:

```
$('select').on('change', function(){
  var limit= $(this).val();
  displayPagination(limit)
});

function displayPagination(limit) {
  var limitPerPage = limit;
  
  //more codes here
  
  //clear pagination before appending new pages
  $(".pagination").empty();
  
  $(".pagination").append("<li class='current-page active'><a class='page-link' href='javascript:void(0)'>" + 1 + "</a></li>");

  for (var i = 2; i <= totalPages; i++) {
    $(".pagination").append("<li class='current-page'><a class='page-link' href='javascript:void(0)'>" + i + "</a></li>");
  }

  $(".pagination").append("<li class='page-item' id='next-page'><a class='page-link' href='javascript:void(0)' aria-label=Next><span aria-hidden=true>&raquo;</span></a></li>");

  //more codes
}
```